# Как правильно обработать ошибки отправляя GET запрос с помощью curl?

Tags: php

Как правильно обработать ошибки отправляя GET запрос с помощью curl?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.test/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


if($content){//проверяем что нету ошибок (ПОПЫТКА проверки)
    var_dump("Нету ошибок");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо просто получить код ответа сервера `curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` если код равен 200 или 304 то все впорядке. если 404 или 405 то уже ошибка. в общем идея в том что просто обработать коды ответов сервера.